# Enumeration through multiple IEnumerable levels

Tags: c#

CollectionT1  implements IEnumerable T1

CollectionT1X implements IEnumerable CollectionT1

The method sketched below enumerates all T1 items held in a CollectionT1X object:

```
IEnumerable<T1> EnumerateT1()
{
    foreach(var t1Collection in this)
        foreach(var t1Item in t1Collection)
            yield return t1Item;
}
```

Is there a more compact way, without applying **yield**, to implement this functionality?

Comment: You can do `return this.SelectMany(c => c);`. SelectMany kind of flattens collections, just what you need.

Comment: As is no, to work through more levels you'll need to do something like `return this.SelectMany(c => c.SelectMany(x => x));`

Comment: Thank you, Evk. I've just deleted my question about multiple levels; was going to find it out myself but you were faster :).

Comment: If you want an undermined amount of levels you could use an iterator with recursion or a queue or stack

Comment: @TheGeneral undermined => undeterminated (but I would hesitate to use recursion in such a case because of the StackOverflowException risk)

Comment: @ZoharPeled yeah you a right, for a few levels it wouldn't be so bad, but definitely is why its worth while to use a queue or stack

Comment: If you like query syntax, you can `return from c in this from i in c select i;` respectively `return from c in this from i in c from x in i select x;`. But this syntax is translated as if it was written with `.SelectMany` with lambda arrows, so it is equivalent. And while this is "without applying `yield`" as you require, the implementation of the `SelectMany` method is done with `yield`.